# Why am I getting: Error in processing request. Do not register any parsers before using the adapter

Tags: node.js, express, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a skill using nodejs + express + express adapter.
I want to add a middleware to intercept the request and check the request body to do some verifications but I get this error:
`Error in processing request. Do not register any parsers before using the adapter`

This is my code for the index.ts:

```
const app: express.Application = express()

// Skill entry point
const skill = application.getSkillBuilder.createSkillForWebService()

const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(skill, config.verifySignature, config.verifyTimestamp)
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: () => void) => {
    console.log(req)
})
app.post("/", adapter.getRequestHandlers())

const listener = app.listen(PORT, function () {
    const { address, port } = listener.address() as AddressInfo
    logger.debug("%s listening to %s%s", app.name, address, port)
})
```

So I get the body printed, but I get the error: **Error in processing request. Do not register any parsers before using the adapter**

But if I remove the line: **app.use(bodyParser.json())**
The skill works, but the **body.req** prints undefined in:

```
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: () => void) => {
    console.log(req)
})
```

Any tip on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Put this middleware in `app.js` above your routes hope it works for you...

Comment: And yes remove body-Parser it's now deprecated and now express gives a parser in-core.